# Three JS: Can LineBasicMaterial be viewed only from one side, i.e, Can we use THREE.FrontSide and THREE.BackSide?

Tags: three.js

I made a grid that looks like a hollow cube. Grid covering sides of the cube. For this grid line I am using LineBasicMaterial. Is it possible to change the properties so that only the grid walls closer to the screen are only visible.

That is, for other materials we have THREE.FrontSide and THREE.BackSide to make it visible only for 180 out of 360 degrees. Is there any similar kind of option for LineBasicmaterial? Or should I use a raycaster (I also have invisible cube for other raycasting tasks) to detect the plane nearer to screen and toggle visibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike triangles/faces, lines don't have orientation/side so it's not possible to have them disappear as you are trying to do.

The only solution I can think of is to use this shader that approximates the look of wireframe:

http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_wireframe